# Ubuntu 18.04 - Lock Executable to Ubuntu dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, executable, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu 16.04, I was able to lock executables to the Unity Launcher. While they were open, I just had to right click, and select "lock to launcher". Then they would stay in the launcher even when they were closed.

In Ubuntu 18.04, I am able to do this for installed applications, by right clicking and selecting "add to favorites" However, this does not work for executables.

How can I lock an *executable* to the Ubuntu dock in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME?